# Cleavage of C-C bond in 1,2-diketo compounds with periodic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

Today we learned the [Malaprade reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaprade_reaction) in class. My teacher told me that a similar reaction can take place when the substrate is a **1,2-diketo** or 1-keto-2-hydroxy or even **1-hydroxy-2-amino**(in presence of periodic acid):-

[image]

(A similar one with 1-hydroxy-2-amino)

I wanted to know the mechanism of this reaction. [This](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.joc.8b03114) is the closest thing I could find.

Comment: Google is your friend!  A search of "periodate cleavage mechanism of diols" gives several well explained examples including https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/10/21/reagent-friday-sodium-periodate/

Comment: Yes, but I want to know that of "diketones"

Comment: The mechanism is the same as the reactive species is the enol

Comment: @waylander, is it thru the enol or the hydrate? Is it known?

Comment: I can find very little literature on the periodate cleavage of diketones to give a definitive answer. It could proceed through the hydrate depending on the ketone and solvent conditions.